# Count for multiple values with single query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like

```
Name      CountryCode 
kabul       AFG
herat       AFG
haag        NLD
tilburg     NLD
breda       NLD
mumbai      IND
delhi       IND
chennai     IND
```

if want to get the count of city for `CountryCode` `AFG` so i will right query 
`select Count(Name) from city where CountryCode = AFG;` and i will get the result

```
Count(Name)
        2
```

but if  I want count for `CountryCode` `AFG`,`NLD`,`IND` in single query like

```
count(Name)
        2
        3
        3
```

How should I write the query to get above result?

Comment: i don't know a city called `haag` in the netherlands. the netherlands does have a city called `den haag`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CountryCode, COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE CountryCode IN ('AFG','NLD','IND') 
GROUP BY CountryCode;
```

Comment: Should be `WHERE CountryCode IN ('AFG','NLD','IND')`

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand the question correctly this should work

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM myTable 
  WHERE CountryCode = 'AFG'
  OR CountryCode = 'NLD'
  OR CountryCode = 'IND'
```

Comment: That will get the number of rows with one of those CountryCodes, but not the count of each of the three.